# Is there any software with which I can create 5.1 surround sound?

Tags: audio-recording

I want to be able to create 5.1 and/or 7.1 surround sound/music. Create a single file which will play music on 5.1 or 7.1 channels and as details as follows.

More explanation:
I want to be able to take 5 or more audio sources and put them together and play them on
separate speakers. Say I have audio sources(a), a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 and I have 5.1 speaker set up. I should be able to play a1 on speaker1, a2 on speaker2,....etc and more mostly leaving sub woofer and woofer (no audio on them).

- Which software helps me to creating this?
- What are the methods you have employed over the years to achieve this?
- Is there any Freeware for creating surround audio?

**Update**:
Available sound card [Creative Sound Blaster Audigy SE 7.1 Soundcard](http://us.store.creative.com/Creative-Sound-Blaster-Audigy-SE-PCI/M/B000LP0R3E.htm)

Comment: What do you mean by creating 5.1 surround sound? You simply wish to mix material in 5.1, or you wish to sound design for 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is plenty of software to do this but you'll need a sound card with the correct number of channels because the soundcard will need to "offer" 6 channels of ASIO to the host program (wavelab or audacity to name but two).

Try reading this article from **[Sound on Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/feb05/articles/steinbergwavelab5.htm)** - it tells you how to configure Wavelab 5 to do it.

Answer (score 1):

5.1 and even 7.1 can often be done with most decent DVD and Bluray authoring packages.  Look to see if they support a Dolby 5.1 or 7.1 encoder (Dolby encoders require a licensing fee, but many authoring softwares include it in the price).  If they do, it is just a matter of mixing audio feeds to go to each of the channels (typically done as mono channels or stereo or center/sub pairs) and then feeding them into the encoder which will generate a Dolby compatible audio stream.

Alternately, you can also get a stand alone Dolby encoder if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

[Logic Pro](http://www.apple.com/logic-pro/) is your solution. You can build a channel-based audio track from scratch, and then split the file over 5.1 and 7.1 channels, using a visual interface.

Keep in mind that you need a 5.1 or 7.1 speaker system to create a 5.1 or 7.1 track.

Answer (score 0):

As AJ and Andy said, there are a plethora of packages which will do this. The challenge you will find is how to arrange the sound balance correctly.

If you are just taking existing stereo and mixing it up to 5.1 then you can choose how far you want to balance depth etc., and these packages usually give you options for automatic surround generation.

If you actually want to create your sound canvas accurately, you need to plan your inputs based on a plan of where the sounds are coming from, and understand delay/lag/phase differences between the different sources so you can make a naturally complete soundscape, or deliberately bring certain items out of the mix to sound articially close, tight or something else.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but for the sake of people searching for answers--I'm answering with actual and practical info.
First, you'll need to author these tracks with a DAW software package that has the capabilities. I prefer Reaper. It's free.
Second, download, install and start using Reaper.
Third, have fun!

Comment: Reaper is a great tool! That being said, I'm not sure this answer is much more clear or useful than the existing ones.

Comment: It isn't clear from this answer whether Reaper can handle encoding a surround mix to CD/DVD, has tools to do the spatial mixing (phase relationships etc), or just has the ability to handle enough D-to-A channels...?